# How to call a Class´s method with a button on a web page - Django -python

Tags: python, django

im starting with django and iot and i've decided to start (for learning purposes) an app that connects to my sensors attached to my raspberry pi.

The thing that im struggling is the next one:

I've done a class for my DHT11 sensor (temperature and humidity), and i've declared all values and wrote a method, which gets and prints the values of the sensor, and made a page where i show all the properties of the object, like "asigned pin" or the "name" of it; all fine until here.
this is the class:

```
class DHT11(models.Model):
    dht_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
    pin = IntegerField()
    status = BooleanField(default=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=15)
    humidity = IntegerField(default=0)
    temperature = IntegerField(default=0)


    def read_values(self):
        self.humidity, self.temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(self.dht_sensor, self.pin)

        if self.humidity is not 0 and self.temperature is not 0:
            self.status = True
        else:
            self.status = False
        
        time.sleep(delay)
        
        print(self.temperature)
        print(self.humidity)
```

The issue is that, in the same page where i show the properties of the object, id like to create a button, and with it call the "read_values" method of the object, and then show the values of temperature and humidity in the webpage that the method returns. ¿how do i do this?, do i need websockets?

Here is an example of the "dht def" in my views.py:

```
def dht(request, dht_id):
dht = DHT11.objects.get(pk=dht_id)

return render(request, "sensors/dht.html",{
"dht":dht

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying call a server side function from front end button click.

Button is a UI object that doesn't have direct access to the DJango methods.

You can call a rest API on button click and get the temperature and humidity data as HttpResponse, then show the data in HTML the way you want

If you want to update the sensor data dynamically, you can go for Sockets

Comment: Oh, i didn't think that, i will try it. many many thanks.

Comment: It worked, and i made it even simpler, because i used my views.py to there there call the object's function, and then pass the temperature and humidity as arguments of the html template. I didnt used a button, so its even better. Thak You Prasobh :)